# Optimized surface covering using rolls of membrane

Tags: linear-programming, applications

I want to cover a surface that has quite a complex geometry limited with straight lines. Covering will be done using a membrane that is sold in 2 meters wide and 25 meters long rolls, with an overlap longitudinally and at the end of each roll of 10 cm.

Is this a common situation? is there a linear program that lets me optimize the way rolls are cut?

Comment: Is this the full description of the problem or do have you omit some information?

Comment: I have omitted the exact surface I want to cover. I am looking for a general method (if it exists) that would be used for any surface that is limited with straight lines.